# jQuery - redirect immediately when session is expired or destroyed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a simple question.

How can i make an page immediately redirect to other page in example www.google.com when a specific session is expired or destroyed.

Here is how i get an session in PHP:

```
<?PHP
$Logged = $_SESSION['LoggedIn'];
?>
```

There are two important things that the jQuery script must do:

1. Without any refresh/reload needed on the page where the script is listening to make a redirect when the session is destroyed for example from another tab in the browser/or the session was expired by a period of time.
2. The script must do a check on every 5 seconds for example.

I am new to jQuery so i'll be very thankfull to you if you can help me for the creation of this script.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use AJAX to check it

jQuery Code - **YourPanelPage.php**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function session_checking()
{
    $.post("ajax-session.php", function(data) {
        if(data == "-1")
        {
            alert("Your session has been expired!");
            location.reload(); // or window.location = "http://www.redirect.com";
        }
    });
}
var validateSession = setInterval(session_checking, 5000);
</script>
```

This jQuery trigger ***session_checking*** function every 5 second and if session expire it will show you a alert and reload

PHP Code to check session - **ajax-session.php**:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset( $_SESSION['LoggedIn']) || $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] == false)
{
    //expired
    echo "-1";
    session_destroy();
}
else
{
    //not expired
    echo "1";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set interval and check for session for every 5 seconds like this:

```
setInterval (function(){
    //your code for checking session goes here
    if(isSessionExpired){
        window.location.href='http://www.google.com';
    }
}, 5000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make a PHP page that validates and returns some JSON (Sorry im a .net dev so cant help you there)

Then you can do something like this, ive plucked it from our much more detailed application and it might have some errors. Let me know if it does. This one is a little different as it sees if the user is still active on the site but you can adapt it to work for you.

The beauty of this one is that you can use it with iframes.

```
var SessionManager = function ()
{
    // Properties
    this.sessionIdle = 0;
    this.persister = null;
};

// Method to reset the persister
SessionManager.prototype.PersistSession = function ()
{
    this.sessionIdle = 0;
};

SessionManager.prototype.Poll = function ()
{
    return $.getJSON("/Services/UtilityService.ashx?action=validateSession&__=" + new Date().toString(),
        function (data)
        {
            if (window.top.session.sessionIdle >= parseInt(data.sessionTimeout, 10))
            {
                window.top.location = '/SignOut.aspx?a=true';
            }
            else
            {
                window.top.session.sessionIdle++;
                window.top.session.persister = window.top.setTimeout(window.top.session.Poll, 60000);
            }
        }
    );
};

if (window.self === window.top)
{
    window.top.session = new SessionManager();
    window.top.session.Poll();
}
else
{
    window.top.session.PersistSession();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `$_SESSION` object is stored on the server, and the JS runs on client side. So the strategy would be:

1. Run a function that makes an AJAX call (see [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)) from the client-side, using JS (see [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval))
2. On the server side, with PHP, check if `$_SESSION['LoggedIn']` is present
3. Return the outcome to the client
4. Parse outcome with JS, and then determine whether user should be redirected

As follow is a very distilled version of the above logic. For your JS, I have chosen to use jQuery for its ease in making cross-browser compatible AJAX calls:

```
$(function() {
    var check = function() {
        // Make AJAX call
        var call = $.get('/path/to/php/file');

        // Check returned promise 
        call
        .done(function(data){ 
            if(!data.loggedIn) window.location.href='http://www.google.com';
        });
    }

    var interval = setInterval(check, 5000);
});
```

For your PHP:

```
<?php
    // Start session
    session_start();

    // Array to return
    $return = [];

    // Check whether the session variable "LoggedIn" is present or not
    if(!isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) || (trim($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) == '')) {
        $return['loggedIn'] = false;
    } else {
        $return['loggedIn'] = true;
    }

    // Echo response in JSON format and close session
    echo json_encode($return);
    session_write_close();
?>
```